# Is it possible to filter type of data entered into console app made in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a console app in VB.net, and need to know how to prevent the app from crashing if user inputs a string into the variable that's declared as an integer. How do I do that?

The app takes a 4-digit item code input by the user, stores it in a variable, and using that code, the app classifies the item and then after the code for all items (which are 500) is entered, the app prints out how many of each item there is. If the input code had a letter or a symbol in it, the app crashes as soon as Enter is pressed, since the variable cannot take a string as an input.I tried looking for another data type that can accept it as an input and then output an error message but I couldn't find anything.

```vb
Dim itmCode As Integer

Console.WriteLine("Input 4-digit item code: ")
itmCode = Console.ReadLine()
Console.WriteLine(itmCode)
```

If anything but a number is entered, it should show an error message saying "Invalid Code Format" and request an input again. It is already part of a loop, but I need to prevent the app from crashing if the input data had a letter by accident.

Comment: `If itmCode Like "####" Then` can be used to check if the input is 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

I'd just read it into a string, check if it's numeric, if it is use it, if it is not, throw your error message.

```
  Dim itmCode As String

        Console.WriteLine("Input 4-digit item code: ")
        itmCode = Console.ReadLine()
        ' do the validation here
        if IsNumeric(itmCode) then 
            ' user input a number
           Else
            ' they did not
        end if
        Console.WriteLine(itmCode)
```

Comment: The old VB6 IsNumeric has been upgraded in .net with the .TryParse methods. If the user enters 33.2 , it would pass your test but not all the characters are digits.

Comment: I did wonder about that as someone else posted a solution involving TryParse, not sure where that answer has gone now. I saw aware that "Numeric" would still fail for an integer, I was mainly concentrating on something that would not bomb out if the user typed in a string. My point was really "accept the user input as a string, then deal with it" rather than the current method of presuming it's a number.

Comment: Actually the best solution is provided by @Slai  in comments. It checks the length and the digits in one simple line.

Comment: Doesn't the OP also have to change the input variable to be a string before they can use that?

Comment: No, `Console.ReadLine` returns a `String`.